# "Simple table" with differing alignments

Tags: tables, luatex

I am facing an issues with tables. 
Currently my MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{.5cm}l}
\hrulefill \\ 
Datum
\end{tabular}% 
\hfill 
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{.5cm}l}
\hrulefill \\ 
Unterschrift 
\end{tabular}% 
\end{document}
```

which produces this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUsFD.png
Now, what I would like to achieve is **first** the top borders to start with the same spacing (as it looks to me the one on the left has more space than on the right). **Second** I would want the part "Unterschrift" to be aligned on the right. I've tried replacing the "l" in the tabular by an "r", as I understood this would change the alignment, but it did not work. What did I miss?

Thank you!

Comment: You are missing that the cells in a row of a tabular are been separated by `&` character... So, you use only one without using `&`... As for the space it can be handled easy by using `\cline` for a `p` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ P{\dimexpr7cm}p{0.5cm}P{7cm} }
        &   &                   \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
Datum   &   &   Unterschrift
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! (I just had to change aray to array from your MWE!)

Comment: @user168390, you are welcome. 'm curious, what you need to change?

Comment: > \usepackage{aray}
to \usepackage{array}

Comment: @user168390, ah, typing error :-). corrected now!